# getting dynamically created XML values with AJAX in js file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml

I have created a dynamic xml file with php as follows

```
('Content-Type: text/xml');?>
<?php $newitem = $_GET["book"];
$action = $_GET["action"];
$qty=0;
$isbnVal="XYZ";
if ($_SESSION["Cart"] != ""){
 $MDA = $_SESSION["Cart"];
 if ($action == "Add"){
  if ($MDA[$newitem] != ""){  
  $tempValue = $MDA[$newitem];
  $value=$tempValue["qty"]+1;
  $MDA[$newitem] =array("qty" =>  $value,"isbn" => $isbnVal);
  }else{$MDA[$newitem] =array("qty" => 1,"isbn" => $isbnVal);}
  }else{$MDA= "";}
}
else{$MDA[$newitem] =array("qty" => 1,"isbn" => $isbnVal);}
$_SESSION["Cart"] = $MDA; 
ECHO (toXml($MDA));                                         
function toXml($MDA){
 $doc = new DomDocument('1.0');
 $cart = $doc->createElement('cart');
 $cart = $doc->appendChild($cart);
 foreach ($MDA as $a => $b){
  //echo "isbn".$b["isbn"];//echo "qty".$b["qty"];  $book = $doc->createElement('book');
 $book = $cart->appendChild($book);

 $title = $doc->createElement('title'); 
 $title = $book->appendChild($title);   
 $value = $doc->createTextNode($a);
 $value = $title->appendChild($value);


 $quantity = $doc->createElement('quantity');
 $quantity = $book->appendChild($quantity);

 $value2 = $doc->createTextNode($b["qty"]);
 $value2 = $quantity->appendChild($value2);

 $isbn = $doc->createElement('isbn');
 $isbn = $book->appendChild($isbn);
 $value3 = $doc->createTextNode($b["isbn"]);
 $value3 = $isbn->appendChild($value3);
 }

        $strXml = $doc->saveXML(); 
        return $strXml;
    }
```

then I'm calling these values in a javaScript file to display. I can get the first and last values from firstChild and lastChild. But I can't get whatever is in the middle. I tried it as follows.

```
spantag.innerHTML += " " +header[0].firstChild.textContent;
spantag.innerHTML += " " +header[0].getElementsByTagName('qty');
spantag.innerHTML += " " + header[0].lastChild.textContent + "  <a href='#' onclick='AddRemoveItem(\"Remove\");'>Remove Item</a> ";
```

only the second code is not working. Plz tell me what I did wrong.Thanx in advance.

Comment: How are you creating the XML file? what class are you using? DOMDocument? what are you doing with the XML file after you generate it? is it being saved on server? or you are generating this XML just for your ajax request?

Comment: I'm using saveXML(). And i'm using the following cording so i think it's using DOMDocument $doc = new DomDocument('1.0');
        $cart = $doc->createElement('cart');
        $cart = $doc->appendChild($cart); I'm displaying the values I took from the xml in the page after I click a link. First and last values get displayed. Even if I have 'qty' in the end instead of 'isbn' it'll get displayed. So i think the way I'm calling it using the tag name is wrong.

Comment: So, you are trying to read an xml (which is already created on server) file's content and display on it your site? If that's the case, can you post the contents of your XML, so I can see the structure.

Comment: I can't find any XML in the server. I think it's returning the xml as a String as it has  $strXml = $doc->saveXML(); 
return $strXml;at the end. I edited the beginning to add the whole php which is creating the XML . when I echoed the commented echos the values were added inside there.

Comment: So you are producing this XML response for your ajax, so that you can show it on the page?

Comment: I can only show whatever I place at first and last.